# What DNS records are required to configure web hosting for a subdomain?

Tags: networking, dns, domain-name, subdomain

I've browsed several questions about DNS setup for subdomains and not quite found an answer, so I'm hoping you can assist.

Our domain name (100storybuilding.org.au) is registered with one provider (NetRegistry), and our main web site is now hosted by SquareSpace (configured using a CNAME record). We need to set up a separate, simple web hosting service with another provider using a subdomain (trapdoor.100storybuilding.org.au).

I was originally advised that we could use their nameservers, and so created NS records for the subdomain with our registrar using the zone management tool available through their control panel. This didn't work, though. Speaking to the hosting provider, I was advised to add an A name record for the subdomain pointing to a specific IP address for the new site, which I've also done. But throughout this process the subdomain has not resolved; I get a failure when using nslookup, as though it's not recognised anywhere.

Currently we have both the A and NS records for the subdomain on our registrar, and I suspect we should only have one or the other; is that the case? I'm rusty with DNS and didn't think this would be complicated, but if anyone can advise what records should be sufficient to for setting this up, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this, you are correct - your problem appears to be that you have both NS and A records.   The A records are being ignored at Netregistry, and there are no A records set up at redyhost.com.

The solution is to either delete the NS records at Netregistry and make sure you have the appropriate A records there, or set up a zone including A records for trapdoor.100storybuilding.org.au at redyhost.com

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I needed to know! Unfortunately NegRegistry have a limit on the number of changes you can make to your DNS in a year and I've now hit it trying to get this sorted out, so I can't even remove those NS records - but at least now I know I need to.